# Can add very large numbers but not small numbers in C

Tags: c

I have a C program that can add large numbers and it works fine but I also need to do add smaller numbers but I get a odd output and am not sure where the error is coming from.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
int num1[255], num2[255], sum[255], m = 0, z, x = 0;
char s1[255], s2[255], in[255];
int l1, l2;

printf("enter the input as a+b=\n");
scanf("%s", in);
for (z = 0; in[z] != '+'; z++) {
    s1[z] = in[z];
    m++;
}

for (z = m + 1; z < strlen(in) - 1; z++) {
    s2[x] = in[z];
    x++;
}

for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
    num1[l1] = s1[l1] - '0';
for (l2 = 0; s2[l2] != '\0'; l2++)
    num2[l2] = s2[l2] - '0';

int carry = 0;
int k = 0;
int i = l1 - 1;
int j = l2 - 1;

for (; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--, k++) {
    sum[k] = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) % 10;
    carry = (num1[i] + num2[j] + carry) / 10;
}

if (l1 > l2) {
    while (i >= 0) {
        sum[k++] = (num1[i] + carry) % 10;
        carry = (num1[i--] + carry) / 10;
    }

    if (carry != 0) {
        sum[k] = carry;
        k = k + 1;
    }
} else if (l1 < l2) {
    while (j >= 0) {
        sum[k++] = (num2[j] + carry) % 10;
        carry = (num2[j--] + carry) / 10;
    }

    if (carry != 0) {
        sum[k] = carry;
        k = k + 1;
    }
} else {

    if (carry > 0)
        sum[k++] = carry;
}

printf("%s+%s=\n", s1, s2);

for (k--; k >= 0; k--)
    printf("%d", sum[k]);
return 0;
}
```

If I enter a values such as:

enter the input as a+b=

9999999999999999999999999999+1=

I get this output which is what I wanted it to be

9999999999999999999999999999+1=

10000000000000000000000000000

When I try something smaller like:

123+456=

The output is different

123ó+456=

16-5-6

I don't know where these numbers are coming from and this keeps occurring with any number less than 9999999999999999999999999999+1= It should work for any number not just a single set.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why? The input format is "a+b=", so the last character is the '=', not a digit!?

Comment: @WernerHenze oh yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (l1 = 0; s1[l1] != '\0'; l1++)
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's a problem: You're checking for `'\0'` in `s1`, but you never set any element of `s1` to `'\0'`, so this will access uninitialized memory and potentially go out of bounds of the array.

You have the same problem with `s2`.

There may be other problems, but this is where I stopped reading.

---

General comments:

- Never use `scanf`.
- If you do, always check its return value to make sure it was successful.
- Never use `%s` with `scanf`. It's a buffer overflow waiting to happen.
- Your code makes very stringent assumption about what the input looks like. If the user doesn't type exactly what your code is expecting, fun things will happen (e.g. the first `for (z = 0; in[z] != '+'; z++)` loop will go out of bounds if there is no `+` in the string). You should probably verify your assumptions and not blindly assume everything is OK.